# Counting number of events on each user in two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to count the number of events that occurred in the past for each user in a table. Actually, I have two dataframe, one for each user at a specific point 'T' in time and one for each event that also occur in time.

This is the exemple of the user table:

```
    ID_CLIENT   START_DATE
0   A   2015-12-31
1   A   2016-12-31
2   A   2017-12-31
3   B   2016-12-31
```

This is the exemple of the event table:

```
    ID_CLIENT   DATE_EVENT
0   A   2017-01-01
1   A   2017-05-01
2   A   2018-02-01
3   A   2016-05-02
4   B   2015-01-01
```

The idea is that I want for each line in the "user" table the count of event that occurs before the date registered on "START_DATE".

Exemple of the final result :

```
    ID_CLIENT   START_DATE  nb_event_tot
0   A   2015-12-31  0
1   A   2016-12-31  1
2   A   2017-12-31  3
3   B   2016-12-31  1
```

I have created a function which leverage the ".apply" function of pandas but it's too slow... If anyone have an idea on how to speed it up it would be glady appreciated. I have 800K line of user and 200k line of event which take up to 3 hours with the apply method.

Here is my code to reproduce :

```
import pandas as pd

def check_below_df(row, df_events, col_event):

    # Select the ids
    id_c = row['ID_CLIENT']
    date = row['START_DATE']

    # Select subset of events df
    sub_df_events = df_events.loc[df_events['ID_CLIENT'] == id_c, :]

    sub_df_events = sub_df_events.loc[sub_df_events[col_event] <= date, :]
    count = len(sub_df_events)

    return count



def count_events(df_clients: pd.DataFrame, df_event: pd.DataFrame, col_event_date: str = 'DATE_EVENEMENT',
                 col_start_date: str = 'START_DATE', col_end_date: str = 'END_DATE', col_event:str = 'nb_sin', events = ['compensation']):

    df_clients_cp = df_clients[["ID_CLIENT", col_start_date]].copy()
    df_event_cp = df_event.copy()
    df_event_cp[col_event] = 1
    
    # TOTAL
    df_clients_cp[f'{col_event}_tot'] = df_clients_cp.apply(lambda row: check_below_df(row, df_event_cp, col_event_date), axis=1)

    return df_clients_cp

# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# ------------------------------------------------------------------

df_users = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'ID_CLIENT': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
    'START_DATE': ['2015-12-31', '2016-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2016-12-31'],
    
})
df_users["START_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df_users["START_DATE"])

df_events = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'ID_CLIENT': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
    'DATE_EVENT': ['2017-01-01', '2017-05-01', '2018-02-01', '2016-05-02', '2015-01-01']
})
df_events["DATE_EVENT"] = pd.to_datetime(df_events["DATE_EVENT"])


tmp = count_events(df_users, df_events, col_event_date='DATE_EVENT', col_event='nb_event')
tmp
```

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the slow exection is caused by `pd.apply(axis=1)`, which is explained [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/avoiding-apply-ing-yourself-in-pandas-a6ade4569b7f).

I estimate that you can improve the execution time by using functions that are not applied rowwise, for instance by using [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

First we merge the frames:

```py
df_merged = pd.merge(df_users, df_events, on='ID_CLIENT', how='left')
```

Then we check where `DATE_EVENT` <= `START_DATE` for the entire frame:

```py
df_merged.loc[:, 'before'] = df_merged['DATE_EVENT'] <= df_merged['START_DATE']
```

Then we group by `CLIENT_ID` and `START_DATE`, and sum the `'before'` column:

```py
df_grouped = df_merged.groupby(by=['ID_CLIENT', 'START_DATE'])
df_out = df_grouped['before'].sum()  # returns a series
```

Finally we convert `df_out` (a series) back to a dataframe, renaming the new column to `'nb_event_tot'`, and subsequently reset the index to get your desired output:

```py
df_out = df_out.to_frame('nb_event_tot')
df_out = df_out.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank's a lot works well !